# Web Service API for creating Manual Rules in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way in Sonar to create Manual Rules with an API that is to say without using the Graphical Interface ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Documented [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743270).

The complete documentation for Sonar's Web service APIs is here:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API

Comment: The problem is that if you look at this [link](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743284) you can get the list of rules with a GET request but you can't add some rules with POST requests. The only thing I can do is add rules manually. As I have many rules to add, it is very impractical.

Comment: @John Follow the link I provided: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743270. Different web service call for manual measures... POST method provided.  Rules are provided and built into the 3rd party tools integrated into Sonar. Not possible for Sonar to manage them, all it does is capture the metrics reported by these external tools

Comment: Manual measures are different from manual rules. I really need to create manual issues. I can do that with POST requests only if I created the corresponding manual rules before. I see only one solution which would be to add the new rules directly in the database in the table RULES. The problem is that it wouldn't be a generic solution and that it wouldn't be compatible with a new version of sonar because the structure of the database could change.

Comment: @John Sounds like a change request.